# Convert a String list to an Int list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, casting

I've got a list of strings, is it possible to convert it to an list of ints?
E.g.:

```
["1","2"] -> [1,2]
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well

```
f :: [String] -> [Int]
f = map read
```

No?

Answer (score 39):

This fails:

```
map read ["1","2"]
[*Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The way to do it is :

```
 map (read::String->Int) ["1","2"]
 [1,2]
 :: [Int]
```

Outside of GHCI, in a .hs file it would be:

```
let intList = map (read::String->Int) ["1","2"]
```

Comment: I know I'm a little late to this conversation, but this can also be done as:
`map read ["1", "2"] :: [Int]`

Answer (score 5):

The general answer to such questions is to split the task up into parts: `[String] -> [Int]` looks like a combination of [`String -> Int`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+Int) and [`[a] -> [b]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5ba%5d+-%3E+%5bb%5d). Hoogle (linked) will give you some results to both, let's see...

> $ hoogle 'String -> Int'
>   Test.HUnit.Base Label :: String -> Node
>   Prelude error :: [Char] -> a
>   Prelude length :: [a] -> Int
>   Data.List length :: [a] -> Int
>   Data.Char digitToInt :: Char -> Int
>   Data.Char ord :: Char -> Int
>   Debug.Trace trace :: String -> a -> a
>   Network.BufferType buf_fromStr :: BufferOp a -> String -> a
>   Network.Socket send :: Socket -> String -> IO Int
>   Graphics.UI.GLUT.Callbacks.Window Char :: Char -> Key
>   Prelude read :: Read a => String -> a
>   Text.Read read :: Read a => String -> a
>   Data.String fromString :: IsString a => String -> a
>   GHC.Exts fromString :: IsString a => String -> a
>   Control.Monad.Trans.Error strMsg :: Error a => String -> a
>   Control.Monad.Error.Class strMsg :: Error a => String -> a
>   ...

Ugh, a lot of rubbish. We can first eliminate those from packages you have nothing to do with...

> Prelude error :: [Char] -> a
>   Prelude length :: [a] -> Int
>   Data.List length :: [a] -> Int
>   Data.Char digitToInt :: Char -> Int
>   Data.Char ord :: Char -> Int
>   Prelude read :: Read a => String -> a
>   Text.Read read :: Read a => String -> a
>   Data.String fromString :: IsString a => String -> a
>   Text.Printf printf :: PrintfType r => String -> r

`error` sounds hardly like what you want. `length` neither. `digitToInt`? Sounds kind of right – and works in fact, but just with single-digit numbers. `read`? Perhaps not the name you would have expected, but if you think about it this is the right thing: converting a string to something more meaningful (like a number) is like reading some text.

Right, on the other side Hoogle gives us the thing we want right up front:

> $ hoogle '[a] -> [b]'
>   Prelude map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
>   Data.List map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
>   Prelude concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
>   Data.List concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
>   Data.Maybe mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
>   Prelude cycle :: [a] -> [a]
>   Data.List cycle :: [a] -> [a]
>   Prelude init :: [a] -> [a]
>   Data.List init :: [a] -> [a]
>   Prelude reverse :: [a] -> [a]

As you see most of these functions are called something with "map", which might again not be the name you expected – but apparently that's what this operation is called! The one you're looking for is quite the simplest.

Finally, we need to combine those two functions. `map` needs another function as its first argument – well, that's obviously `read` then! So you simply apply `map` to `read`. The next argument is the list of `[a]`s: aha, we're done already!

You can check this by launching up ghci:

> Prelude> :t map read
>   map read :: Read b => [String] -> [b]

There's still this `b` in here instead of `Int`, but never mind that: `b` can be any type you want! – provided it has a `Read` instance. `Int` has:

> Prelude> :i Int
>   data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#  -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
>   instance Bounded Int -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
>   instance Enum Int -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
>   instance Eq Int -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
>   instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
>   instance Num Int -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
>   instance Ord Int -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
>   instance Read Int -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
>   instance Real Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
>   instance Show Int -- Defined in `GHC.Show'