# Haskell string to list

Tags: list, haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert string list to int list in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919937/convert-string-list-to-int-list-in-haskell)

I have a string `12345`. How can I show it in list form like `[1,2,3,4,5]`? And also what if i have a string like `##%%`? I can't convert it to `Int`. How can view it in the form `[#,#,%,%]`?

Comment: These aren't duplicates.  One is converting a string to a list, the other is converting a list of strings to a list.

Comment: In Haskell "12345" IS in fact ['1','2','3','4','5']. Is that what you want or is it ["1","2","3","4","5"]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`intersperse`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:intersperse)

```
myShow :: String -> String
myShow s = concat ["[", intersperse ',' s, "]"]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

map digitToInt "12345"
```

Answer (score 6):

You should map the function read x::Int to each of the elements of the string as a list of chars:

```
map (\x -> read [x]::Int) "1234"
```

If you have non-digit characters you should filter it first like this:

```
import Data.Char
map (\x -> read [x]::Int) (filter (\x -> isDigit x) "1234##56")
```

That results in:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: This works but what if i have a string like "##%%" ?

Comment: This counts that the string is made up by digits. If you want to filter the characters that are not digits you should use a filter. I will edit the answer

Comment: I changed my question as well. Actually i don't want to split nondigits. I want to view them in list form.

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at this answer? 
[Convert string list to int list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919937/convert-string-list-to-int-list-in-haskell)

A String is just a list of characters in Haskell after all. :)

Comment: I checked it but when i try to convert a string like "&%" it gives parse error.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [splitEvery](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.2.3/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asplitEvery) with length 1