# Haskell non-digit string list to a different list

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have a list ['%','&','/']. How can i convert it into the form [%,&,/] ?

Comment: `[%,&,/]` is not a list of int. It's not even valid Haskell. You need to be clearer on what you want.

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be type of int. It just has to shown like [%,&,/].

Comment: Your question is **very** unclear. What is `[%,&,/]`? Is it a list with 3 operators? Then the short answer is that it's not possible as those 3 operators have different types, hence can't be in the same list. I assumed you mean `&&` by `&`

Comment: Well i want to print like that.

Comment: Why did you entitle your question "Haskell non-digit string list to int list" then?

Comment: @thetux4 so what you want is a *string* with that text?

Comment: -1 for unnecessarily difficult to understand, overly specific question. You don't want an "int list" or a "different list". The form [%,&,/] is invalid Haskell syntax and can't possibly be any kind of list. It sounds like you want a *string* like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell string to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679797/haskell-string-to-list)

Comment: What on earth is the type signature for the desired result?

Comment: @sclv: [Haskell string to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679797/haskell-string-to-list) is not a duplicate, It's asking how to convert a string to a list whereas this question, as I understand it, is asking how to convert a list to a string i.e. the opposite process. Admittedly this question starts to make sense when you read the other though...

Comment: @Troubadour I think you got me.

Comment: @sclv Previous question was about a list consisting of digits at first. I'm asking another question in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"[" ++ intercalate ',' list ++ "]"`

`intercalate` is declared in `Data.List`.

Comment: This gives me "[+,%,/]", something which i dont want.

Comment: Then it sounds like what you want is impossible.

Comment: @thetux4: that is *exactly* what you want. Strings in Haskell are lists of characters. They are displayed (when printed) with quotes around them. If you want to display a string without quotes, call `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 6):

```
myShow :: [Char] -> String
myShow s = concat ["[", intersperse ',' s, "]"]
```

Use it like this:

```
putStrLn (myShow ['%','&','/'])     -- prints [%,&,/]
```

---

But if you want this to work with `show` and `print`, you will have to define your own type:

```
data MyChar = MyChar Char

instance Show MyChar
  where show (MyChar ch) = [ch]
```

And then operate on `[MyChar]` rather than `[Char]`:

```
let myList = map MyChar ['%','&','/']
-- ... do whatever you want with myList ...
print myList                        -- prints [%,&,/]
```

Comment: Commendable effort. Unfortunately, I suspect it will be wasted.