# How to convert list of numbers to list of strings in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, integer, converters

How to convert list of numbers to list of strings(one string = one number from list) in Haskell.

[Int] -> [String]

Examples: [1,2,3,4] -> ["1","2","3","4"]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919937/convert-string-list-to-int-list) which do the inverse (string to int)

Comment: If you have a [function](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+String) `Int -> String` you could make a function `[Int] -> [String]` using [map](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D)` map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a function `f :: a -> b`, then `map f :: [a] -> [b]` applies `f` on all the list elements.

The function `show` can convert "printable" types in their string representation. In particular, one of the possible types for `show` is `Int -> String`.

Use both tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write a function to print an element from 0, this could be another solution

```
cp_log :: (Show a) => [a] -> String

cp_log [] = ""
cp_log [x] = (show x)
cp_log (x:xs) = (show x) ++ ", " ++ cp_log xs
```

A complete example can be the following one

```
cp_log :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
    
cp_log [] = ""
cp_log [x] = (show x)
cp_log (x:xs) = (show x) ++ ", " ++ cp_log xs

quick_sort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quick_sort [] = []
quick_sort (x:xs) =
  let smaller = quick_sort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
      bigger = quick_sort [a | a <- xs, a > x]
  in smaller ++ [x] ++ bigger

main =
  let sorted = (quick_sort [4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2])
  in putStrLn (cp_log sorted)
```

Comment: All the TS was needed is simple `map show`. What you came up with is a rough equivalent of `intercalate "," . map show`. So your answer doesn't answers the question, and is excessively complicated at the same time. Please pay attention to what was the question about next time :)

Comment: ops, I'm sorry :) I try only to post a craft approach, but you have right

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, please accept my apologies. Your haskell is impressive, I think you could help somebody with their pending questions, let's forget about this ancient-one :)

Comment: don't worry @madbird, I will happy if you remove the downvote :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my downvote is locked until the answer is edited. Add a couple of lines, or, maybe, replace `let` with `where`, so I'll be able to remove my vote.

Comment: Done @madbird :) I preferer to use the following code because I think is more readble

Answer (score 0):

Using the list monad:

```
f :: [Int] -> String
f xs = do 
         x <- xs
         return $ show x
```

or equivalently:

```
f' :: [Int] -> [String]
f' = (>>= return.show)
```